# How to check if user is active and then log out

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I have a login form and it works, but I have to add condition if user is active or not. If he's not active, then redirect to some page show_error. I'm using CodeIgniter.  here's my model: I tried with this function "is_active_user" but it's not working.

```html
 public function login()
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('users');     
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',sha1($this->input->post('password')));
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->row_array();            
    }
  public function is_active_user() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');         
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" || deactivated_at IS NULL ');
        $result=$this->db->get();
          
            if($result->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $result->row_array();
                
            } 
            return false;
             
    }
```

My controller is:

```html
 public function login ()
    {
            
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $user=$this->user_model->login();
        
        $is_active=$this->user_model->is_active_user();
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Потребителско име', 'trim|required|callback_login_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Парола', 'trim|required'); 

        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {

            $this->index();
        }
        else 
        {
            if(count($user) > 0 && count($is_active) > 0)    
            {
                $this->load->library('session'); 
            
                 $data = array(
                    'username' => $user['username'],
                    'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
                    'is_logged_in' => TRUE,
                    'role_id' => $user['role_id']
                
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);         
           
            }
        }
    }
```

How to check if user is active or not?

But no result.
Now I tried with:

```html
 public function login()
    {

        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('users');     
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',sha1($this->input->post('password')));
        $this->db->where('deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR deactivated_at IS NULL');
        
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->row_array();            
    }
```

But it logs me with another profile, not this profile with username and password that I have filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function login()
{
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('users');     
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password',sha1($this->input->post('password')));
    $this->db->where('deactivated_at <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00"');
    $this->db->where('deactivated_at IS NOT NULL');
    $result=$this->db->get();
    return $result->row_array();            
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It's better in this function, not to write another. :)

Comment: I edited my question, I don't know why when I use this code up, I log in with another profile, not that with these username and password that I've typed.

Comment: You couldn't know wich user is logged in if you don't use sessions. First, move db related code to model. All your login method code should be regular model code. In controller would stay something like `$logged_in = $this->Login_m->login_check($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password')); if ($logged_in) {$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $username);}` Also you need logout function that would unset logged_in key and let application know user is logged out.

Comment: I have made it in that way. $user=$this->user_model->login(); $data = array(
                    'username' => $user['username'],
                    'user_id' => $user['user_id'],
                    'is_logged_in' => TRUE,
                    'role_id' => $user['role_id']
                
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);

Comment: But when I want to add in model function check if user is active and then I log in, it is in another profile. My model function login is: $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('users');     
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',sha1($this->input->post('password')));
        $this->db->where('deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR deactivated_at IS NULL');
        
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->row_array();

Comment: I would suggest you that you split logic and issues and ask another question on site.